# Why Unexpected Indent?

Tags: python, indentation

Why does this happen?

```
def LoadPackageList():
    try:
        #Attempts to load package list... Adds each neccessary attribute into array
        print("Loading Package List... please wait")
        packages = []
        packagelisturl = os.getcwd() + "packages.list"
        dom = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen(packagelisturl))
        try:
            for eachattributeofpkglist in dom.GetElementsByTagNameNS(packagelist, 'packages'):
                packages.append({
                    'title': node.getAttribute('title'),
                    'shortname': node.getAttribute('shortname'),
                    'dlurl': node.getAttributes('dlurl'),
                    'description': node.getAttributes('description'),
                    'tags': node.getAttributes('tags'),
                    'infopage': node.getAttributes('infopage'),
                    'quality': node.getAttributes('quality'),
                    'id': node.getAttributes('id')
            })

        except LoadPackageListFailed:
            print("Loading Package List failed... try again soon or manually update this release!")
            Write2ErrorLog(LoadPackageListFailed)
#Indent Here Fails            
def Usage():
#prints usage and closes
    print ("Invalid Argument Specified, please retry using the format stated below\n")
    print ("*** Simtho Usage Parameters ***\n")
    print ("-i Installs Local App, include full path")
    print ("-u Uninstalls Installed App,include ID or Name")
    print ("-l Lists all installed Apps and their ID")
    print ("-a Lists All Apps in Repository")
    print ("-s Downloads and Installs App from repository, enter the title or id number")
    print ("-w Downloads and Installs Single App from a full link")
    print ("-r Removes All Packages installed\n")
    print ("*** End of Simtho Usage ***")
    os._exit(1)
    return;
```

Comment: Where exactly is the indent? Could you show the actual output and what you were expecting?

Comment: Try running it through something that shows whitespace. On a *nix machine, use `od -c yourfile.py` to see the characters. That might be useful, although there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: If you still haven't figured it out, copy and paste the above code over top of your own and it should fix the problem.  If it does not, the problem was not in the above code, but in something adjacent, as ~unutbu suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't the try on line 2 have an except, finally or else associated with it? Or is this some new Python idiom I haven't seen before?

Comment: Yeah, that did it, cuz I put an un-needed try statement or w/e kind of thing try is

Comment: Hey cuzzin, you ain't got no code that's raisin' `LoadPackageListFailed`

Answer (score 7):

Try running it through `python -t` and see if there is a mixture of tabs and spaces somewhere in there.

As a side note: use [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#module-optparse) to process command line parameters. It will make your life much easier and produce a nice consistent interface.

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted works just fine. Therefore, check the lines immediately above the part you posted. If that does not help, please post the exact error message and a little more of the code.

**Edit**: Also check that you do not have a mixture of tabs and spaces.

**Edit 2:** (In response to more code posted by the OP).
Aha. Every `try` requires an `except`. In the definition of `LoadPackageList`, there are two `try`'s. The inner one has an `except` block, but the outer one is just a bare `try`.